# SFMC Android Handling Notifications not through the SDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, android, mobilepush-android, sdk

I'm working with an app vendor who for some reason doesn't want to let the SDK handle the Marketing Cloud push notifications in their `onMessageReceived` method in their notification service.

```
MarketingCloudSdk.requestSdk(sdk -> sdk.getPushMessageManager().handleMessage(msg));`
```

How do we reproduce what the SDK does when handling messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are wanting to handle this without the SDK then the answer should be pretty obvious: get the payload sent by Google, inspect the values and take the appropriate actions to populate and display a notification.  If that presents a problem for them then I would insist that they use the SDK ;)

The SDK will, of course, handle all the possible use-cases presented by the Marketing Cloud.

Notification handling can also be customized or overridden while still leveraging the SDK.  Details of how to do this can be found http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/notifications/customize-notifications.html